# Добавление всех элементов списка

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно добавить новый тег `li` с помощью jQuery так чтобы была и дата и имя и текст который ввел пользователь! Вот код:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", "add-comment", function() {
    var form = $("form[name='form']");
    form.css("display", "block");
    $("#add-comment").replaceWith('form');

  });


  $(document).on("click", "input[name = 'send']", function() {
    var myName = $("input[name = 'myName']").val();
    var comment = $("textarea[name='comment']").val();
    var newDate = $('.date_comment').val();
    var newComment = $("<li class='comment-item'>" + "<p class='text_comment'>" +
      comment + "</p>" + "</li>").appendTo("#new");

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="new">
  <li class="comment-item">
    <span class="name_comment">Боб</span>
    <span class="date_comment"> 17 июня 2017 год</span>
    <p class="text_comment">Привет</p>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="container">
  <form name="form" id="form" action="#" method="post" onsubmit="return 
    false">
    <textarea id="textarea" name="comment" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="Добавить комментарий" id="done">
  </form>
  <a href="#" onclick="return false" id="add-comment"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on('click', 'button.send', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var myName = $('input[name="myName"]').val();
  var newDate = $('input[name="newDate"]').val();
  var comment = $("textarea[name='comment']").val();
  $('ul#new').append('<li class="comment-item"><span class="name_comment">' + myName + '</span><span class="date_comment">' + newDate + '</span> <p class="text_comment">' + comment + '</p></li>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="new">
  <li class="comment-item">
    <span class="name_comment">Боб</span>
    <span class="date_comment"> 17 июня 2017 год</span>
    <p class="text_comment">Привет</p>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="container">
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="myName" placeholder="Имя" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="newDate" placeholder="Дата" /><br />
    <textarea name="comment" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Комментарий"></textarea><br />
    <button class="send">Добавить комментарий</button>
  </form>
</div>
```